# Typescript + Webpack doesn't work with types

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a simple class

```
export default class Scott {
  hello() {
    let color: string = "blue";
    return true;
  }
}
```

However Webpack 4 throws this error: ERROR in ./src/js/test.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

If I change the "let" to let color = "blue"; then it works.   Anytime I try to introduce a type I get the unexpected token error.

Is there something I need to include in the tsconfig file?

Comment: Like anything that's not JS, if you want to compile it with Webpack, you'll need a loader.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make sure that you have a Typescript loader in your webpack config, so that it understands how to load .ts files.

[ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) and [awesome-typescript-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader) are both good options.

Each one describes how to set it up within your webpack config.